# ngx-intl-tel-input - 'PhoneNumberUtil' is not exported by node_modules\google-libphonenumber\dist\libphonenumber.js

Tags: angular, gulp, ngx-international-phone-number

I'm using below NPM packages as suggested by package,

```
 "ngx-intl-tel-input": "2.2.1",
 "ngx-bootstrap": "^5.1.1", 
 "google-libphonenumber": "^3.2.2",
 "intl-tel-input": "^14.0.6",
```

And as suggested, imported below in app.module

```
BsDropdownModule.forRoot(),
NgxIntlTelInputModule,
```

but when I do the gulp rollup, it is giving below error

> Error: 'PhoneNumberUtil' is not exported by node_modules\google-libphonenumber\dist\libphonenumber.js

in gulp file, i have also tried below lines,

```
 rollupCommonjs({
        namedExports: {          
            'node_modules\google-libphonenumber\dist\libphonenumber.js': ['libPhoneNumber.default.PhoneNumberUtil']
or
 'node_modules\google-libphonenumber\dist\libphonenumber.js': ['PhoneNumberUtil']
        }
      }),
```

but nothing seems to work, any suggestions or any other library instead of ngx-intl-tel-input